# Two Lists Into One Dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

If I have two lists

```
dates = []
closes = []
```

And I have one dictionary

```
dict2write = {'date', 'close'}
```

How do I fill the dictionary with the two lists? I'm going to write the dictionary into a csv.

Comment: ``data = dict(zip(dates, closes))``

Comment: The two different solutions to two different problems offered by James and ex0ns should make it apparent that you need to describe what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: thanks james, that's great. seems clear enough to me ollie

Comment: To potential answers -- Please don't ask to clarify the question in your answer. It's bad form :/

Comment: To potential answerers -- "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a dictionary use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to form tuples and then `dict()` to create the dictionary.

```
>>> dates = ['2014-07-31', '2013-11-22', '2014-01-01']
>>> closes = ['what', 'is', 'this?']
>>> zip(dates, closes)
[('2014-07-31', 'what'), ('2013-11-22', 'is'), ('2014-01-01', 'this?')]
>>> d = dict(zip(dates, closes))
>>> d
{'2013-11-22': 'is', '2014-07-31': 'what', '2014-01-01': 'this?'}
```

But if you want to write the data to a CSV file, you don't need to create dictionaries, you just need to zip the lists.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(dates, closes))
```

Output in data.csv is:

```
2014-07-31,what
2013-11-22,is
2014-01-01,this?
```

One other thing worth mentioning, if the lengths of the lists vary you can use `itertools.izip_longest()` to zip the lists. e.g.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest
dates = ['2014-07-31', '2013-11-22', '2014-01-01']
closes = ["what's", 'this?']
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(izip_longest(dates, closes))
```

This will leave the missing columns empty in the resultant CSV file:

```
2014-07-31,what's
2013-11-22,this?
2014-01-01,
```

Comment: aha, thanks for this. give a minute to see if it works for me

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a key/value pair, are you looking for that:

```
dict2write = {}
dict2write['date'] = dates
dict2write['close'] = closes
```

Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to do?

Are `dates` and `closes` the same length and you want to make a dictionary with `dates` as the keys and `closes` as the values like `{dates[0]: closes[0], dates[1]: closes[1], ...}`

If so, you can use the fact that you can [construct a dictionary out of a list of (key, value) pairs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) by making that list using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
 dict2write = dict(zip(dates, closes))
```

But if that's not what you want, if you want `'date'` and `'close'` to be the keys, then it's even easier:

```
dict2write = {'date': dates, 'close': closes}
```

(Note as an aside that the "dictionary" in your question, `{'date', 'close'}`, is *not* a dictionary, but a *[set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)*.)

Or do you want something yet different?